# Why doesn't this cron job run?

Tags: linux, cron

My cron job isn't running on my system. Any idea why?

```
% ps aux | grep cron

root      4213  0.1  0.2   5548  1496 ?        
               Ss   12:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

crontab.txt:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/seq 10 2>&1 testlog.log
(newline)
```

To schedule this job, I issued

```
% crontab crontab.txt
```

but nothing prints to screen, and nothing is written to the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron jobs don't print to screen, and you've not redirected stdout to the file, you need an extra `>` before the filename

your `2>&1` sends stderr to stdout, but stdout goes nowhere.

try `2>&1 > filename`, or perhaps `> filename 2>&1`.

*on phone at the moment so can't check*